# can't use MFCaptureToFile with startech video grabber

Tags: c++, visual-studio, video, ms-media-foundation

I have a [startech composite to usb video grabber](http://www.adorama.com/stsvid2usb23.html?gclid=CjwKEAjwrIa9BRD5_dvqqazMrFESJACdv27G7Z5piQHlk8cmfIFjBd2IXSDjwGGXlHTd487uwg2KYhoCoa7w_wcB) connected to a small security cam that I want to use in order to capture video for a custom Windows application. I am using [MFCaptureToFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663604(v=vs.85).aspx) as an example for learning the yoga of how to do this in Visual Studio with C++.

The example code builds and runs fine on my Windows 7 setup and performs normally with a cheapo [logitech usb webcam](http://www.tenettech.com/product/2410/logitech-webcam-pro-9000), but not with my little security cam+video grabber rig. However, the camera does work in Windows. I can use other applications (other custom ones written using the EmbarcaderoXE/borland/vcl based video grabbing stack) work perfectly.

When I break on the callback function:

```
HRESULT CCapture::OnReadSample(
HRESULT hrStatus,
DWORD /*dwStreamIndex*/,
DWORD /*dwStreamFlags*/,
LONGLONG llTimeStamp,
IMFSample *pSample      // Can be NULL
)
```

with the logitech cam, `hrStatus` is `S_OK` (as it should be). When I break using the startech device it is `-1072875772` which is `FFFFFFFFC00D3704` in hex and a string of Chinese characters in human-readable unicode format. So that is of little help.

Edited due to first comment by Mike Vine:
Actually, the code stands for MF_E_HW_MFT_FAILED_START_STREAMING. Why does it fail?

The EmbarcaderXE-based video grabbing app that I have uses VCL as a backend, which I've read is incompatible with visual studio? For various reasons I need to do this in VS.

Comment: 0xC00D3704 is MF_E_HW_MFT_FAILED_START_STREAMING

Comment: Thanks! I actually knew that but somehow didn't spot the code in there.  I don't see why it's preceded by all these F bytes, and why the NotifyError(hr); in the example code doesn't show the error to me. Windows doesn't make it easy sometimes...

Comment: The extra F bytes are sign extension on a negative number. Has nothing to do with Windows.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you for clarifying. I simply meant that I don't understand why the code is FFFFFFFFC00D3704 instead of 00000000C00D3704.

Comment: Something is possibly wrong with H.264 stream. I used to deal with other StraTech products and I had to patch other problematic things with their [cheap] hardware because they cut corners on their side.